# How do I have Facebook installed and how can I remove it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I was using Everything and I noticed I have a few `App.dll` files all at about 250mb.

I checked the path and they all contain something like

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Facebook.Facebook_186.2619.19263.0_x86__8xx8rvfyw5nnt
```

I tried accessing `WindowsApps` directory but **Access Denied**

[image: directory_listing]

I checked my apps and didn't find anything related to Facebook.

---

I'm wondering;

1. How can I get rid of it?
2. How can it have gotten there (so I can remove it).

Answer (score 0):

I gave myself permission (as owner) from the Security > Advanced tab and went and deleted those folders (which there were quite a few).

I'm still unsure how/why they were even there...

Comment: This is dangerous.  Changing the permissions on WindowsApps It is best to uninstall UWP applications through the Windows Store.  Facebook is not installed by default.  At some point, it must have been installed without you realizing it.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked in apps in windows 10 settings and found nothing. Also there were like 5 directories all containing the entire "Facebook" app. I never installed it.